Moving picture like a carousel
SO here is the deal, I have a typescript project that looks like this

const MainPage = () => {
const allBooks = [, , , , ];
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
const moveLeft = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex - 1 + allBooks.length) % allBooks.length);
};

const moveRight = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % allBooks.length);
};

return (
    <div className="body-container">
        <div className="left-button-container">
            <button className="left-button" onClick={moveLeft}>
                LEFT
            </button>
        </div>

        <div id="bannerBooks">
            {allBooks.map((book, index) => (
                <div
                    key={index}
                    className={`book-container ${
                        index === currentIndex ? "active" : "inactive"
                    }`}
                >
                    {book}
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>

        <div className="right-button-container">
            <button className="right-button" onClick={moveRight}>
                RIGHT
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
);

};
export default MainPage;

So here is my MainPage.css
#bannerBooks {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 20px;
}

.book-container {
    transition: transform 0.3s ease, opacity 0.3s ease;
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: translateX(10px);
}

.book-container.active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.book-container.inactive {
    opacity: 0.5;
    transform: scale(0.8);
}

.left-button-container, .right-button-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.left-button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    top: 600px;
}

.right-button {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
    top: 600px;
}


Believe me Ive triend everything, you can check kia.com and see they got similar function but with cars I want to do something same.
As you can see I have elements like books, and I want to create a function that will be working like a carousel for example
buttonLeft Book1 book2 book3 book4 book5 buttonRight
when you press buttonLeft the book in the middle moves to the left and book that was on the right moves to the center and the same with the right button. I know I can use chatGPT but I DONT USE IT ON PURPOSE FOR NOT BECOMING A CHATGPT SENIOR, thank you everyone for the attention :)

so you want someone to write the setCurrentIndex for you? What's the difference between someone writing it for you and chatgpt writing it for you? You've done exactly the same amount of coding in both cases

I’m afraid SO is not an ab initio coding service. Have a go at coding this yourself. There is a lot of advice out there on how to implement a carousel. If still stuck put the relevant code into your question along with a description of what isn’t working and what debugging you have tried.

StackOverflow is not a free coding service. Please be specific about your problem, provide [mre] and other relevant information like error log.

@Bravo there is actually a big difference, when asking a question in stackoverflow most people doesnt really gives you a code, Im not really asking to code at least some documentations, while chatgpt doesnt really answers my question, for me its more helpfull when human being asnwering my question, thank you for your comment

@zobomber Lemme repeat: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. Don't expect code, expect answers. The more you provide information about your problem the easier you get answers. What are setCurrentIndex() and allBooks? Do you expect people to somehow know what they are and run your code by guessing?
